# Definition of an initial segment

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Is this definition of an initial segment correct?

> Let $\preceq$ be a linear ordering of a set $A$, and $B \subsetneqq A$. $B$ is an initial segment of $A$ under $\preceq$, if $\forall a \in A, \forall b \in B(a \preceq b \to a \in B )$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is what I would use too. In words: $B$ is an initial segment if with every element it also contains all elements smaller than it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is one possible definition of *initial segment*. Sometimes the term *initial segment* is defined a little more narrowly; I've seen it used to mean what I would call *proper initial segment*, i.e., an initial segment by your definition that is not all of $A$, and I've seen it used to mean $\{x\in A:x\preceq a\}$ for some $a\in A$. However, what you've defined is, I think, the most common meaning of the term.

Comment: M.Scott, thanks soo much!! :)

Comment: @Garnak: You're very welcome.

Comment: Just to be clear to whomever might read this, the version $\{ x \in A \colon x \preceq a \} $ is not the same as the OP's version. Think of the set $\{ q \in \mathbb{Q} \colon q < \sqrt{2} \} $.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Does it matter if the order is strict or just partial? Meaning does the definition applies equally if we're talking about $\preceq$ or $\prec$?.

Comment: @Daniela: The OP’s definition would yield the same initial segments if you replaced $\preceq$ with $\prec$.