# Definition of Dedekind cut as initial segment

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, definition, order-theory

the definition of Dedekind cut by initial segment is correct:

"let $\preceq$ be a linear ordering of a set $A$, and $B \subsetneqq A$, $B \neq \emptyset$, $B$ is Dedekind cut of $A$ under $\preceq$ if $B$ is [initial segment of $A$ under $\preceq$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464347/definition-of-initial-segment) and $B$ has no largest element under $\preceq$"

???

Thanks in advance!

P.S.= in this case "$B$ has no largest element under $\preceq$" means "$\forall a \in B, \exists b \in B(b \preceq a \wedge b\neq a)$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking of the construction of the reals from the rationals, you need to add two more conditions: $B\ne\varnothing$, and $B\ne A$. If you don't add these conditions, you get something order-isomorphic to $[0,1]$, i.e., to the extended reals (with $\pm\infty$). If you're thinking of the construction of the Dedekind completion of a linear order, what you have is fine.

Comment: M.Scott, ok... in my precedent post the simbol $\subset$ means "proper subset ($B \subset A$ if $B \subseteq A$ and $B \neq A$), therefore the two conditions are implicit/included, or not?

Comment: @Garnak: One of them is, but you still need to add the condition that $B\ne\varnothing$. (Since some people use $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$, it's safer to write $\subsetneqq$ when you mean *proper subset*. This is `\subsetneqq`.)

Comment: M.Scott, okok.. thanks! I corrected my precedent posts!!

Comment: @Garnak: You're welcome!

Comment: M.Scott, I edited my question, is correct?

Comment: @Garnak: In the P.S. you mean $\forall b\in B\exists b'\in B(b\preceq b'\land b\ne b')$. If you're thinking of the construction of the reals from the rationals you still need to add the requirement that $B\ne\varnothing$. If you're thinking of the Dedekind completion, you **don't** want to add that condition, but you **do** want to allow $B$ to be all of $A$.

Comment: M.Scott, okok.. Suppose I'm thinking of the construction of the reals from $\mathbb{Q}$... is correct? :)

Comment: @Garnak: Yes, it is.

Comment: M.Scott, ok.. but, if $\preceq$ is linear ordering of $A$, and $B \subsetneqq A$, $B \neq \emptyset$, then is false $\forall a \in B, \exists b \in B(b \preceq a \wedge b\neq a)$, or not? $B$ has largest element!?

Comment: @Garnak: That depends entirely on $B$. Some non-empty proper initial segments have largest elements (and therefore are not Dedekind cuts), and some do not have largest elements (and therefore are Dedekind cuts). If $A=\Bbb Q$, for example, $B=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q\le 1\}$ has a largest element and is therefore not a Dedekind cut, even though it is a proper non-empty initial segment. $B=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<1\}$, on the other hand, is a Dedekind cut.

Comment: M.Scott... okok thanks soo much!! ;)

Comment: @Garnak: You're very welcome.